# Excel Files not getting inserted into the table with Values

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel

I have to insert an excel file into the table with values. The ID of the column should be fetched by the dropdown values. Rest of the column values are been inserted through the excel sheet. The problem is that, I have written the code, but the values are not getting inserted into the table.
Please see the code for your reference:-

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name;
    string storename;
    string address;
    string city;
    int Id;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        name = row["Merchant_Name"].ToString();
        storename = row["Store_Name"].ToString();
        address = row["Store_Address"].ToString();
        city = row["City"].ToString();
        Id = int.Parse(row["CategoryId"].ToString());
        this.InsertRows(Id, name, storename, address, city);
    }
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string sPath = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(sPath);
        Response.Write("<script>alert('File uploaded successfully');</script>");
    }
}

private void InsertRows(int Id, string name, string storename, string address, string city)
{

    string sSourceConstr1 = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\AgentList.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""");
    string sSourceConstr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""");

    OleDbConnection sSourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(sSourceConstr);

    string constrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constrng))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert Into MerchantDataTable values (@CategoryId, @MerchantName, @StoreName, @StoreAddress, @City)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryId", Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MerchantName", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreName", storename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreAddress", address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a SQLBulkCopy with column mappings too. If you have a large number of rows it may be more efficient than a parameterized query running in a loop. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: yes tim, agreed with you. Tried with that also, but couldn't succeed. Please help

Comment: I noticed you've got two Excel connection strings. Are you using the right one and opening a file?

Comment: Yes, I m using the right one."sSourceConstr". but still my code is not working as required

Comment: Try moving your Open command outside your using statement and your close statement to a finally block?

Comment: I didn't got u. Can you write the code please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64632/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-tim).